# Rendering and baking help

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I have a simple question and I'm not sure where to go for help so that's why I'm asking here.

Is there any possible way I can get my bakes to look like my renders? I know it can't be exact but the shadows and lighting looks amazing while I'm rendering but once I bake the lighting is smudged out and ugly. I'm new to everything so sorry if this may be a dumb question.

Render:
[image]

Bake:
[image]

Comment: please add some images of what you are saying

Comment: Here are screenshots of what I mean... Render:
https://i.gyazo.com/bf6335575efe9eb0fc62fd437be3c1af.png                                  Bake:https://i.gyazo.com/51564a1bf3d70c2ed470aa1bb48810e1.png

Comment: which its the bake and the rendered? neverming i re read xD...well did you bake with indirect and direct lights off?

Comment: well did you bake with indirect and direct lights off?

Comment: No, both are on.. the person who taught me didnt go into detail about baking so im still learning.

Comment: and this has pbr textures? or its for an game engine without those, because thats why you want to bake the lights?

Comment: Yes, it has everything but it still bakes weird... and correct the game is without those which is why im trying to bake it on there.

Comment: well obviously you wont get the same exact viewport render look in the baked textures.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here but that object shown reflects light. It isn't possible to bake light reflection ideally for it to be shown as when rendering since that is computed in real time depending on environment and surface, hence it isn't necessary it's what you actually want to do. Usually albedo, roughness and metallic maps are baked (if metallness workflow) with sometimes specular, then light reflection are computed by the end application. Lastly please include screenshots in the question body